# OpenFDA: Is there a data source which provides descriptions of the ingredients listed in EAFUS DB?

Tags: data-request, openfda

Is there a data source which provides descriptions of the ingredients listed in [EAFUS DB](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/fcn/fcnNavigation.cfm?rpt=eafusListing)?

I have been able to find details from varied sources (PubChem, Wikipedia etc etc) but I need something that explains the presence of a particular ingredient in that particular food.

Searching via regnum (see EAFUS Table) using [CFR Title 21 Search](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/fcn/fcnNavigation.cfm?rpt=eafusListing) leads to mixed results.

Edit: Updated link to EAFUS DB